editing hexo static website problem while using placeholders in the layout
  
    
      

  
    
  
after that appear in the generated html meaning hexo couldnot deal with it am i right?
I try choosing the banner I need in the front markdown folder ,so I edit the theme/layout/partial/header but after generating I expect reflection on the generated Html but I got the same code I wrote on the header.ejs file I am using Landscape theme in Hexo





Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

  '); background-size: cover;"> I corrected the layout.ejs code 

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
